# How do I make this script stop restarting the adapter after 10 restarts?

Tags: windows-7, networking, batch, bash-scripting

How do I make this windows batch script stop restarting the adapter after 10 restarts?

```
@echo off

:loop

timeout /t 8

echo Checking...

ping -n 1 192.168.1.1|Findstr /I /C:"timed" /C:"unreachable" /C:"find host" /C:"failure"

if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Restarting...

netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin="disabled"

netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin="enabled")

goto loop
```

Comment: [For - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
@echo off
set /a restarts=1
:loop
timeout /t 6
echo Checking...
ping -n 1 192.168.1.1 | findstr /i /c:"timed" /c:"unreachable" /c:"find host" /c:"failure"
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Restart attempt #%restarts%...
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin="disabled"
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin="enabled"
set /a restarts+=1)
if %restarts%==6 exit
goto loop
```